Dimension of the collection of $n$-linear functions
My question is referred to the textbook “Linear Algebra, S. Friedberg, A. Insel and L. Spence.” Here gives the definition of the $n$-linear functions:
The following exercise of such section:
says the collection of $n$-linear functions over a field $F$, say $L_n$, is a vector space over $F$. What is the dimension of $L_n$? (I guess that dim$(L_n)=n^2$.)
Next, here gives the definition of the alternating $n$-linear functions:
If we define $Alt_n$ as the collection of alternating $n$-linear functions over a field $F$, is $Alt_n$ a subspace of $L_n$? If yes, what is the dimension of $Alt_n$?

Hint: Let $e_1^,...,e_n^$ be a basis for $F^n$. We can write $a_i = \sum_{k_i=1}^n [a_i]{k_i} e{k_i}^$, and so $\delta(\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \ \vdots \ a_n\end{bmatrix}) = \sum_{k_1} \cdots \sum_{k_n} [a_1]{k_1} \cdots [a_n]{k_n} \delta(\begin{bmatrix} e_{k_1}^ \ \vdots \ e_{k_n}^* \end{bmatrix})$. In particular, any such $\delta$ is defined by the $n^n$ numbers $\delta(\begin{bmatrix} e_{k_1}^* \ \vdots \ e_{k_n}^* \end{bmatrix})$. However, if $\delta$ is alternating, 'most' of those numbers are zero, so considerable reduction is possible.

Note that the collection of mappings  $\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \ \vdots \ a_n\end{bmatrix} \to  [a_1]{k_1} \cdots [a_n]{k_n} $ form a basis for the $n$-linear functions.

This is just a matter of grinding through (a lot of grinding).
Let $I = \{(k_1,...,k_n) |  k_i \in \{1,...,n\} \}$. Define $\phi_k(\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix}) =  [a_1]_{k_1} \cdots [a_n]_{k_n}$, with each row $a_i \in \mathbb{F}^n$.
Then the $|I|=n^n$ functionals $\phi_k$ form a basis for the $n$- linear functions $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F}) \to \mathbb{F}$. To see this, suppose $\delta:M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F}) \to \mathbb{F}$ is $n$-linear. Let $e_i$ be the $i$th row of zeroes with one in the $i$th position. Note that
$\phi_h( \begin{bmatrix} e_{k_1} \\ \vdots \\ e_{k_n}\end{bmatrix} ) = \delta_{h_1 k_1} \cdots \delta_{h_n k_n}$ (unfortunate clash of symbols here, hopefully clear in context). Then $n$-linearity shows that
$\delta = \sum_{k\in I} \delta( \begin{bmatrix} e_{k_1} \\ \vdots \\ e_{k_n}\end{bmatrix} )\phi_k$, hence the $\phi_k$ spans $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F}) \to \mathbb{F}$, and if $\sum_{h\in I} \alpha_h \phi_h = 0$, then evaluating at $\begin{bmatrix} e_{k_1} \\ \vdots \\ e_{k_n}\end{bmatrix}$ shows that $\alpha_k = 0$, hence the $\phi_k $ are a basis and so $\dim (M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F}) \to \mathbb{F}) = n^n$.
It is straightforward to check that $Alt_n$ is a vector space. Suppose $\delta$ is alternating, by expanding $\delta ( \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_i+a_{i+1} \\ a_i+a_{i+1} \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} ) = 0$ we can check that $\delta ( \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_i+a_{i+1} \\ a_i+a_{i+1} \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} ) = -\delta ( \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_{i+1} \\ a_i \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} ) $, in particular, swapping any two adjacent rows changes sign. This also shows that if any two rows are identical, the the functional will have value zero.
Suppose $\sigma$ is a permutation of $1,...,n$. The permutation may be written as a product of pairwise transpositions (cf. bubble sort), that is $\sigma = \tau_1 \cdots \tau_l$, and $\operatorname{sgn} \sigma = (-1)^k$. In particular, this shows that
$\delta ( \begin{bmatrix} a_{\sigma_1} \\ \vdots  \\ a_{\sigma_n} \end{bmatrix} ) = \operatorname{sgn} \sigma \ \delta ( \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots  \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} ) ) $.
The above shows that any $n-$linear $\delta$ can be written as
$\delta = \sum_{k\in I} \delta( \begin{bmatrix} e_{k_1} \\ \vdots \\ e_{k_n}\end{bmatrix} )\phi_k$, and since $\delta$ is alternating, if will be zero for any $k \in I$ that is not a permutation. Hence we can write
$\delta = \sum_{k\in S_n} \delta( \begin{bmatrix} e_{k_1} \\ \vdots \\ e_{k_n}\end{bmatrix} )\phi_k = \sum_{k\in S_n} \operatorname{sgn} k \ \delta( \begin{bmatrix} e_1 \\ \vdots \\ e_n\end{bmatrix} )\phi_k = (\delta( \begin{bmatrix} e_1 \\ \vdots \\ e_n\end{bmatrix} )) \sum_{k\in S_n} \operatorname{sgn} k \ \phi_k $.
In particular, all alternating $n$-linear functionals are multiples of the functional $d=\sum_{k\in S_n} \operatorname{sgn} k \ \phi_k $, so $\dim Alt_n \le 1$, and since $d( \begin{bmatrix} e_1 \\ \vdots \\ e_n\end{bmatrix} ) = 1$, we see that $\dim Alt_n = 1$.
